# Configuring http_backend in puppet 4

Tags: couchdb, puppet, hiera

I have a problem while configuring Puppet 4 master to work with HTTP requests so I can use CouchDB for hiera.
These are the steps I did so far:

1. created new CouchDB with `test` database
2. created new document called `common`
3. `gem install hiera-http-1.0.0`
4. put the `http_backend.rb` file in `/opt/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/mpdules/hiera_http` and `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/hiera-http`

When I run `gem list` I can see:

```
Hiera (3.2.0)
Hiera-http (1.0.0)
```

Now, when I try running `hiera common` or anything else I get ERROR :

```
'require' : cannot load such file -- lookup_http (LoadError)
```

My `hiera.yaml` looks like :

```
:backends: 
- http
```

And, of course, all the required settings (host,port..)

When i run `puppet agent -t` on the agent I get

```
cannot load backend http: no such file to load -- hiera/backend/http_backend at site.pp
```

Answer (score 2):

Your steps 3 and 4:

- `gem install hiera-http-1.0.0`
- put the `http_backend.rb file` in `/opt/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/mpdules/hiera_http` and `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/hiera-http`

need to be replaced by:

- `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install hiera-http`

That will ensure the hiera-http hiera backend gem is automatically properly installed and configured for the ruby that puppet uses.

If you want to use the system ruby for puppet so that it recognizes the hiera-http installed from the system gem, then you need to install puppet, facter, and hiera with gem and not your OS package manager.